# Is there a way to directly create a raster image from bytes for canvas (not show) display?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, raster

I am creating a 512x512 raster image in a byte string in "RGBX" fomat (from a memory-mapped device), and cannot get it to display in a label image. The image displays just fine with show(). I just need to quickly transfer the byte data directly to the image input for a button or label, is that possible?

I have tried converting the image with .convert, doesn't do RGB, PhotoImage wants a string variable only, base64.b64encode() spawns an unkillable zombie on my machine. I have tried to make the image object 'static' in the demo, I think most answers to similar problems point to making the image stay around to be displayed. An image I load by opening any file displays fine with the label or button image methods. io.BytesIO doesn't support the image into it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
#import base64

root=tk.Tk()

kimage_width = 512
kimage_height = 512
kimgSize = (kimage_width,kimage_height)

# Make a color 256K pixel photo of 'stuff', in bytes
# The image data is in RGBX order

ColorImage=b''

for i in range (0,int(kimage_width * kimage_height/8)):
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>2) & 0xFF]) # Red
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>7) & 0xFF]) # Green
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>6) & 0xFF]) # Blue
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>0) & 0xFF]) # Not used

# copy it 8 times

ColorImage+=ColorImage+ColorImage+ColorImage # 4
ColorImage+=ColorImage # total = 8 copies

# make a PIL image?

kimage = Image.frombytes('RGBX', kimgSize, ColorImage, 'raw')

kimage.show() # Display image if not a tkinter window

#######photo = base64.b64encode(ColorImage) # Crash - makes a zombie

b=tk.Button(root,justify = tk.LEFT)
b.config(image=kimage, width="512", height="512")
b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

ImageMajick shows the 512x512 color image  in 1 window, the tk window should have the same image placed into a button image, but tk errors out with :
_tkinter.TclError: image "" doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this, but missed a couple of bits:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root=tk.Tk()

kimage_width = 512
kimage_height = 512
kimgSize = (kimage_width,kimage_height)

# Make a color 256K pixel photo of 'stuff', in bytes
# The image data is in RGBX order

ColorImage=b''

for i in range (0,int(kimage_width * kimage_height/8)):
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>2) & 0xFF]) # Red
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>7) & 0xFF]) # Green
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>6) & 0xFF]) # Blue
    ColorImage+=bytes([(i>>0) & 0xFF]) # Not used

# copy it 8 times

ColorImage+=ColorImage+ColorImage+ColorImage # 4
ColorImage+=ColorImage # total = 8 copies

# make a PIL image?

kimage = Image.frombytes('RGBX', kimgSize, ColorImage, 'raw').convert('RGB')

kimage.show() # Display image if not a tkinter window

pI = ImageTk.PhotoImage(kimage)
b=tk.Button(root,justify = tk.LEFT)
b.config(image=pI, width=512, height=512)
b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]